# Stack Level Too Deep, but unsure what is exactly causing the infinite recursion

Tags: ruby

So my research on this seems to indicate that the there is something in here that is causing infinite recursion, but I'm not sure waht it is. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

```
def initialize(_val)
    @start_value = _val
end

def method_missing(method, *args)
    if method.starts_with?("plus") then
        num = method[4 .. method.length]
        if (/^[\d]+(\.[\d]+){0,1}$/ === num) then
            number = Integer(num)
            self.class_eval("def #{method}; return @start_value + x; end")
        self.plus(number)
        else
            super.method_missing
        end
    else
        super.method_missing
    end
end

end
```

Comment: That's strange. I would expect your code to immediately throw a NoMethodError for calling `starts_with?` on a Symbol. Also you're using `super` wrong - it should just be `super`. By adding `.method_missing`, you're calling `method_missing` on the result of calling the superclass's `method_missing`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't do this:

```
super.method_missing
```

You want this:

```
super
```

In both cases you'd be using `super` with no args, which is the proper way to call an ancestor's version of a method, in this case `method_missing`. But in your version you're then calling `method_missing` redundantly on the result, which is where it gets all infinitey.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious explanation would be if you don't have `plus` defined as an instance method. But why not add a `puts method` to the top of your `method_missing` method so you can see what's going on?